# How can I make these divs grow to fill the size of their container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to write a function that takes a users input to create a grid (16x16, 32x32 etc). The issue I'm having is getting the appended divs to scale properly to the container.

here is what it looks like:
[image: here is what it looks like]

```js
function createGrid(input) {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.gridContainer');
  for (let i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';
    for (let j = 1; j <= input; j++) {
      const pixel = document.createElement('div');
      pixel.className = 'pixel';
      row.appendChild(pixel);
    }
    gridContainer.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.pixel {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 8px;
  min-height: 8px;
  border: 0.1px solid black;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer">

</div>

<input class="gridSize" type="number">
```

I thought adding flex 1 with a minimum width and height to the divs would do the trick so I must be missing something here. (I'm a noob so I apologize in advance if it's a super easy fix).

Comment: either use flex-grow or simply use grid.

Comment: I tried using flex-grow but nothing seems to change. As for using grid, I specifcally chose flex to get more comfortable with it. Does it not make sense to use flex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the CSS you are looking for:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pixel {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 8px;
    min-height: 8px;
    border: 0.1px solid black;
}

.gridContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: stretch;
}
```

In short, there are some adjustments regarding the `.gridContainer` and the `.row` classes.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the quick reply Martin, much appreciated! I spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure this out haha